# Wcf serialization and data format over the wire

Tags: wcf

I have an understanding on how the format of the data will be when its sent on wire and before its sent over wire to the client while using WCF. Please let me know if its right and correct me if I am wrong.

**Case 1 :HttpBinding is used. When returning a WCF service call to the client:**

When a method returns a dot net object, it will be first serialized into netdatacontract serializer format. This serialized data will be put inside a soap envelope .This soap will be  converted into binary when its sent to network wire.On the client end riverse of these steps will be done.

**Case 2 :NetTcpbinding. When returning a WCF service call to the client:**

When a method returns a dot net object, it will be first serialized into netdatacontract serializer format. This data will **not** be converted into soap format. Instead, the serialized format is directly converted into binary while putting the data on the wire. On the client side, reverse of the above is done.

If the above statements are right ,
Is this why they say netbinding uses binary encoding and is optimized for performance ?

Comment: Case 1. Nope. (XML) `DataContractSerializer`. Case 2. Nope. `NetDataContractSerializer` is already in a binary format (binary XML format called FastInfoSet). NetTcpBinding is faster because FastInfoSet is faster than vanilla XML.

Comment: Hi Aron, would you give me the exact steps and the format of data while sending data over the wire and how does it vary against using a nettcpbindig vs httpbinding.

Comment: As WCF is an abstraction technology (most people for instance are happy not knowing assembly when they use a compiler) you don't need to know how it works or the exact steps it takes (unless it is not doing exactly what you want). Also, given that WCF is a HUGE library, I don't think I could explain what I do know about the framework. Could you tell me what you want to know?